# Don't reset line numbers using Verse package

Tags: line-numbering, verse

I would like line numbers to **not** reset when using `verse` environment.

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{verse}
\poemlines{5}
\begin{document}

\chapter{}
\begin{verse}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\!

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\!
\end{verse}

{\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{}}
\begin{verse}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\!

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\!
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to make the line numbering continue counting even though you've started a new `verse` environment?

[image]

Comment: Milo :-) my sincere welcome. I not forgot your glasses :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The (redefined) `verse` environment sets the relevant counter `poemline` to 0 at the start.

Remove the setting. One also needs to subtract one at the end of the environment, because the counter is stepped at the beginning.

When needed you will issue `\setcounter{poemline}{0}` to reset the numbering.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\verse}
  {\setcounter{poemline}{0}}% find
  {}% replace
  {}{}% auxiliary arguments
\xpretocmd{\endverse}{\addtocounter{poemline}{-1}}{}{}

\poemlines{5}
\begin{document}

\chapter{}
\begin{verse}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\!

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\!
\end{verse}

{\let\clearpage\relax \chapter{}}
\begin{verse}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\!

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit\\!
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The numbering is not right, the first line of the second environment should be 9. This can be fixed by replacing with `\addtocounter{poemline}{-1}` (or `\m@ne` as used in the package itself) to counter the effect of `\refstepcounter` that is used at the start of the environment.

Comment: @Marijn You're perfectly right! Fixed, but in a different way.